# only one margin of facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use facet grid to display only the right margin not the bottom margin.

**Example Code**

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars) + facet_grid(cyl ~ vs, margins=TRUE)
```

**Currently Outcome**
[image]

**Desired Outcome**
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars) + facet_grid(cyl ~ vs, margins="vs")
```

[image]

---

When this answer was written, this behavior was not documented. Now, it is in the [facet_grid](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html) documentation

> **margins** either a logical value or a character vector. Margins are additional facets which contain all the data for each of the possible values of the faceting variables. If `FALSE`, no additional facets are included (the default). If `TRUE`, margins are included for all faceting variables. If specified as a character vector, it is the names of variables for which margins are to be created.

(Thanks to [@Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108828/harry) for pointing this out.)

Comment: Very undocumented. Only found out about by checking the issue tracker, seeing it was "working", and then chasing through the code to figure out how it was actually specified.

Comment: Very nice indeed!  thanks Brian.  That one is not easily found.  I've been pulling my hair out for 2 hours.  I'm very appreciative. +1 and the check